# code is skipping firebase snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to run the following code, but for some reason the snapshot is never running as a result of the while loop.  When I add the while loop the only thing that prints is `"current count is <2"` because the assignment of currentCount above is skipped for some reason.  Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
    //below sets the default selection as pitcher
    pitcher = true
    batter = false
    //******Needs to show the default selection as well
    batterCheck.hidden = true
    batterButton.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    pitcherButton.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    //below defaults to hiding the results related data
    ResultsLabel.hidden = true
    playName.hidden = true
    pointDiff.hidden = true

    var playRef = ref.child("LiveGames").child("05-25-17").child("RedSox")
    playRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.currentCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(snapshot)
        print("***" + String(self.currentCount))
    })

    while(self.ended != true) {
        if(self.currentCount < 2) {
            print("current count is < 2")

        } else {
            playRef.child(String(self.currentCount-2)).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2) in
                var hitterRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Hitter")
                var pitcherRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Pitcher")
                self.batterName.text = (String(hitterRef.childSnapshotForPath("/fName")) + " " + String(hitterRef.childSnapshotForPath("/lname")))
                self.pitcherName.text = (String(pitcherRef.childSnapshotForPath("/fName")) + " " + String(pitcherRef.childSnapshotForPath("/lname")))

            })
            self.currentCount += 1
        }
    }
    print("labels updated")

}
```

However when I comment out the while loop the currentCount is set to the correct value.  Any ideas on what this while loop is doing to block the firebase snapshot from running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock` is called asynchronously. That means that it will be executed in another thread and not in the scope of the ViewDidLoad method.

If you stick a breakpoint outside the completion block and one inside the completion block it will become more clear.

What you need to do if you need to update the labels after the 'observeSingleEventOfType' is complete, you should move you 'update' code in a separate method and call it in the completion block of the observeSingleEventOfType method.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 //Your code here...
 var playRef = ref.child("LiveGames").child("05-25-17").child("RedSox")
    playRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.currentCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        self.updateLabels()
    })
   //Your code here...
}
func updateLabels() {
  //Your update code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this when I had not set a rule for the parent I was observing.